# Game time speeds up the slower the frame rate, delta time inconsistent across different framerates

Tags: c++, game-development

Here is how I am calculating the delta time:

```
currentTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
deltaTime = std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::seconds::period>(currentTime - lastCurrentTime).count();
lastCurrentTime = currentTime;
```

From the very beginning of this project I noticed the delta time did not give me consistent results across different frame rates. Everything that uses this deltaTime speeds up the slower the framerate is, but as an example, here is how the camera moves forward:

```
playerPosition += playerForward * speed * deltaTime;
```

I could show you the entire main loop, but that shouldn't matter, however long it takes should be accounted for. I remember one time I had a problem with std::chrono and it was because the compiler "optimized" the start timer to a completely different place. Could that be happening here? And if so, is there a better way of calculating delta time in C++?

Comment: FYI, you can post to [gamedev.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`, it is implementation-defined. Stick to `std::chrono::steady_clock` instead. Additionally, your problem is here: `std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::seconds::period>(currentTime - lastCurrentTime).count();`. You are defining the period as a variable-length instead of a constant length which will cause your deltaTime to change "length" between calls.

You can simplify your problem by defining a using for a float-based seconds:

```cpp
namespace TimeUtils {

using FPSeconds = std::chrono::duration<float>;
using FPMilliseconds = std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>;
using FPMicroseconds = std::chrono::duration<float, std::micro>;
using FPNanoseconds = std::chrono::duration<float, std::nano>;
using FPFrames = std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<1, 60>>;
using Frames = std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::ratio<1, 60>>;


template<typename Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock>
[[nodiscard]] decltype(auto) Now() noexcept {
    return Clock::now();
}

std::chrono::nanoseconds GetCurrentTimeElapsed() noexcept {
    static auto initial_now = Now<std::chrono::steady_clock>();
    auto now = Now<std::chrono::steady_clock>();
    return (now - initial_now);
}

//...
} //end TimeUtils

static TimeUtils::FPSeconds previousFrameTime = TimeUtils::GetCurrentTimeElapsed();
TimeUtils::FPSeconds currentFrameTime = TimeUtils::GetCurrentTimeElapsed();
TimeUtils::FPSeconds deltaSeconds = (currentFrameTime - previousFrameTime);
previousFrameTime = currentFrameTime;

//...Prevents death-spiral when stepping through debugger
#ifdef DEBUG_BUILD
    deltaSeconds = (std::min)(TimeUtils::FPSeconds{TimeUtils::FPFrames{1}}, deltaSeconds);
#endif

//...

Update(deltaSeconds);
```

Now you can declare your `deltaTime` as `TimeUtils::FPSeconds deltaTime` in function arguments. This allows you to express it in any `std::chrono::duration` format you want as it will be converted automagically:

```cpp
void Foo(TimeUtils::FPSeconds deltaSeconds);

Foo(TimeUtils::FPMilliseconds{10.0f}); //Automatically converted to 0.010f seconds
```

Comment: Just switching to steady_clock fixed all of my problems haha so I can't thank you enough. When I get more time I'll try out your other advice. (sorry I took so long, the holidays had me pretty busy, happy holidays!)

Comment: Actually, the steady_clock alone just made it better, it didn't completely solve the problem, but now the problem seems to be gone after I copied your code. Thanks again.